# How do I collect the check box name and send the request?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form

I am using 'react-hook-form' and I need to use checkbox to send a post request

the request formate will be like this

{"project":['A','B','C','D']}

but what I got is , it's {"project":['on','on','on','on']} or  {"project":true}

is there any way to get the checkBox name by clicking it?

```
<Form.Group controlId="product">
            <Form.Label>Product</Form.Label>
            {productArray.map((product) => (
              <div key={product} className="mb-3">
                <Form.Check
                  ref={register({
                    required: "Required",
                  })}
                  custom
                  name='products'
                  type='checkbox'
                  id={product}
                  label={product}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add value for your checkbox component.

```
               <Form.Check
                  ref={register({
                    required: "Required",
                  })}
                  custom
                  name='products'
                  type='checkbox'
                  id={product}
                  label={product}
                  value={product}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
```